# NGINX regular expression to match location with optional parameter

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I like to match location with two optional parameters so it it matches

```
/images/my.jpg
/images/my.jpg/200
/images/my.jpg/200/
/images/my.jpg/200/400
/images/my.jpg/200/400/
```

I am using three match groups so that I can get the matched part in $image, $width and $height variables.

I tried this query. It works only if the full location is given but it does not match if one of the parameter is missing

```
~ ^/images/(?<img>.+?)/(?<width>\d+)/(?<height>\d+)?$
```

I also tried which does not work at all

```
~ ^/images/(?<img>.+?)?(/?<width>\d+)?(/?<height>\d+)?$
```

please help - I have input data here. https://regex101.com/r/qU7tI7/6

nginx config here

```
 server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  f.myhost.com;
    set $sitename f.myhost.com;

    root $root_folder/myhost.com/files;
    set $path_info "";

    location / {
            root   /var/www/myhost.com/app/api/;
            include conf.d/site.template;
            add_header X-test "root";
    }

    location /files {
            root   /var/www/myhost.com/app/;
            include conf.d/site.template;
    }

    location ~ ^/images/(?<img>[^/]+)(/(?<width>\d*))?(/(?<height>\d*))?$ {
    #       root   /var/www/myhost.com/files/;
            alias   /var/www/myhost.com/app/test/$image;
    #       include conf.d/site.template;
            add_header X-test "test";
            add_header X-width "$width";
            add_header X-height "$height";
            add_header X-name "$image";
            image_filter resize $width -;
            image_filter_jpeg_quality 75;
            image_filter_buffer 8M;


    }

 }
```

Comment: Try: `^/images/(?<img>[^/]+)(/(?<width>\d*))?(/(?<height>\d*))?$`

Comment: Thanks Richard, it matches all but last case at regex101  but again not in nginx

https://regex101.com/r/qU7tI7/8

Comment: I missed the last case, it needs another `/?` before the `$`. What do you mean "not in Nginx"? Do you have a conflicting location?

Comment: update post with my config

Comment: There is a typo in your config - you have `img` in some places and `image` in others.

Answer (score 0):

Try following regular expression:

```
/^(\/images\/)([\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6}|[\d\.]+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)?$/igm
```